# Need help creating transparent MP4 vidoes to be used in HTML5 video

Tags: ios, ipad, html, video, transparent

I have made a transparent .flv video
I used jwplayer to play .flv video which works fine and the transparency is there but my main problem is to make it work on iOS systems,since iOS do not support .flv playing i had to used html5 video tag to play the files hence i converted the .flv to all the html5 video formats i.e .webm, .ogg,.mp4 which do not retain the transparency of the .flv file
So i need to have a transprarent video working on iOS system, especially iPad.

Comment: This question is only very loosely related to software development.  It sounds more like you need help finding the right software to convert your video files.  You would probably be better served at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before in iOS, and also the video always goes fullscreen.

I make a little trick to solved this using sprite image CSS technique and html5 audio.
you can refer to this thread : [Multiple HTML5 media elements on one page in iOS (iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387853/multiple-html5-media-elements-on-one-page-in-ios-ipad/9496057#9496057)
In case of you, you can make a sprite image CSS - with transparent effect.